# Reverse for 'usecase-details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['usecase\\-details/(?P<ucid>[^/]+)\\Z'] Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have three models user, usecase, and usecase assign:
I have two views redirecting to the same page to show the details of the usecase and to assign new users and unassign users

I'm trying to execute the logic of this method:
DELETE FROM `usecase_assign` WHERE `usecase_assign`.`user_email` = 'nmbarak';

How can I get the user_email from the template and pass it in the view to delete it?
what I tried is to create two views, the first one for showing the usecase details and assign new users, the second one to un-assign and to redirect to the same page.

My usecase_assign model:

```
class UsecaseAssign(models.Model):
    usecase_assign_date = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True, auto_now_add=True)
    usecase = models.ForeignKey(Usecase, models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')
    usecase_role_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

```
my views:
@user_login_required
def view_usecase_details(request, ucid):
    usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid).all()
    usecase_details = usecase_details.prefetch_related("usecaseids")
    users = User.objects.all() #SELECT user_email FROM usecase_assign WHERE usecase_id LIKE 'NN245';
    usecase_assigned = UsecaseAssign.objects.select_related('user_email').values_list('user_email__user_name').filter(usecase_id=ucid) #to show list of users working on uc
    if request.method=='POST' and 'assignuser' in request.POST:
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        userAssignCheck = UsecaseAssign.objects.filter(user_email=user_email, usecase_id=ucid)
        if userAssignCheck:
            messages.error(request, "user already added!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
        else:
            userAssignObj = UsecaseAssign.objects.create(user_email_id=user_email, usecase_id=ucid)

        if userAssignObj:    
            messages.success(request, "User was Successfully Assigned with Usecase!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))

    context = {'usecase_details': usecase_details, "users": User.objects.all(), 'usecase_assigned':usecase_assigned, "users": users}
    return render(request, 'UsecaseDetails.html', context)        

@user_login_required
def unassign_emp(request, eid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        unassign_emp = UsecaseAssign.objects.filter(user_email_id=eid).delete()
        return redirect('usecase-details')
```

my template:

```
{% for result in usecase_details %}
<div class="card card-body shadow-sm mb-4 mb-lg-0">
    <form class="mb-card" action="/usecase-details/{{result.usecase_id}}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row mb-4">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
            <label class="h5" for="user_email">Assign new users:</label>
            <select name="user_email" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="user">
                <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                {% for user in users %}
                <option value="{{ user.user_email }}">{{ user.user_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}                             
              </select>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="assignuser" value="Submit Changes">
      </form>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-0 border-bottom">
            <div>
                <label class="mb-card h5" for="user_email">Assigned users:</label>
                {% for user in usecase_assigned %}
                <form action="/unassign-emp/{{result.user_email}}" method="POST" style="display: inline !important;">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="btn-group me-2 mb-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">{{user|join:', '}}</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-x-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M12 0H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zM6.854 6.146 8 7.293l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L8.707 8l1.147 1.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707 6.854 9.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 6.146 6.854a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708z"></path>
                      </svg>                   
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}  
            </form>
            </div>          
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

urls:

```
    path('usecase-details/<str:ucid>', av.view_usecase_details, name="usecase-details"),
    path('unassign-emp/<str:eid>', av.unassign_emp),
```

I've been on this for days I tried to put everything in one view still having problems with urls I accept another ways to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the error message is most certainly comming from the redirect because you need to add the parameter ucid that you use in the path/url statement:

```
    path('usecase-details/<str:ucid>', av.view_usecase_details, name="usecase-details")
```

```
@user_login_required
def unassign_emp(request, eid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        unassign_emp = UsecaseAssign.objects.filter(user_email_id=eid).delete()
        return redirect('usecase-details')

should be soemthing like:
        return redirect('usecase-details', ucid=XXX)
```

2. it is more "django like" to used the url tag {% url ... %} together with the name from path statement in templates:

```
    <form class="mb-card" action="/usecase-details/{{result.usecase_id}}" method="POST">

should rather be:
    <form class="mb-card" action="{% url 'usecase-details' ucid=result.usecase_id %}" method="POST">
```

same for path "unassign-emp":

```
    path('usecase-details/<str:ucid>', av.view_usecase_details, name="usecase-details"),
    path('unassign-emp/<str:eid>', av.unassign_emp, name="unassign-emp"),
```

and in the template:

```
   <form action="{% url 'unassign-emp' eid=result.user_email %}" method="POST" style="display: inline !important;">
```